# jQuery hover() flickering/fading

Tags: jquery, hover, fade

Trying to get an image "B" to overlay over image "A" when mouse hovers over image "A". Ideally i want it to fade in.

HTML:

```
    <div id="prod-image">
        <img src="../imgs/products/mens/image-A.jpg" class="box-shadow" />
    </div>
    <div id="prod-overlay">
        <img src="../imgs/image-B.jpg" />   
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(function() {
    $("#prod-image").hover(function() {
        $(this).next().fadeIn().show();
    }, function() {
        $(this).next().fadeOut().hide();
    }); 
    });
```

Problem is every time the mouse moves it retriggers the hover effect meaning it blinks on and off as it retriggers every pixel the mouse moves. How can I make it only trigger the second action when we leave the container div, not just move about within it?

Thanks for any help.

[EDIT]

CSS:

```
    #prod-overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
    top: 0px;
    }
```

Basically it just sits this div on top of the other. I don't think it's really relevant? Unless the z-index is messing things up.

[EDIT 2]

for anyone who might care/stumble across this... this fixes it:

```
$("#prod-image").hover(function() {
    $("#prod-overlay").stop(true).fadeTo("normal",1);
}, function() {
    $("#prod-overlay").fadeTo("normal",0);
});
```

Seems a little unnecessary to me but who am I to criticise jQuery?

Comment: Could you also post any CSS along with this code?

Comment: i think u should use `mouseenter` `mouseleave`  instead `hover` according to your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about getting your 2 images within a same container and apply your hover triggering on this container?

```
<div  id="container">
    <div id="prod-image">
        <img src="../imgs/products/mens/image-A.jpg" class="box-shadow" />
    </div>
    <div id="prod-overlay">
        <img src="../imgs/image-B.jpg" />   
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(function() {
$("#container").hover(function() {
    $("#prod-overlay").fadeIn().show();
}, function() {
    $("#prod-overlay").fadeOut().hide();
}); 
});
```

It should work !

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much fixes it, it doesn't fade out though it just disappears, why would that be?

Comment: Actually it's pretty unreliable, half the time it doesn't hide at all. This should be so simple!

Comment: fadeOut and hide are being run at the same time so it's hiding before it even gets chance to start fading. In reality though you don't need to have the hade part as it will be hidden once the fadeOut is completed.